# How can i achieve LogicApp->APIM->SFTP

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-api-management, rate-limiting

We'd like to pick a file in this structure LogicApp->APIM->SFTP. APIM because we want to define a staticIP for SFTP server to whitelist. I understand how we can restrict/monitor calls to LogicApp via APIM but i require help in the other direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can restrict/monitor the calls (call rate) to a specified number per basis of time period specified using the **rate-limit policy** that prevents API usage spikes on based of per subscription.

Set the calls rate on number of calls box and renewal period in seconds using Inbound Processing option:

[image: inboundprocessing]

Caller will receive `429 Too many requests` as response & status code if the call rate is exceeded:

[image]